# RadioButton altera o checked ao rolar Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, rolamento, radiobutton

Boa tarde, estou com um problema com RadioGroup em uma listview.
Seguinte, quando eu marco um RadioButtom e utilizo o scroll da minha listview, a marcação que eu fiz aparece em outro RadioButto e não no que eu tinha selecionado. 
 Segue o código do meu adapter:

```
class AdapterAmcPersonalizada extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal;
    private final Activity act;

    private AvaliacaoMensal flag;


    public AdapterAmcPersonalizada(List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal, Activity act) {
        this.mensal = mensal;
        this.act = act;


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensal.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mensal.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_layout_lista_amc, parent, false);

        final AvaliacaoMensal mensalAmc = mensal.get(position);

        //pegando as referências das Views
        TextView potencial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.potencialLetra);
        TextView questao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questao);
        TextView titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        RadioButton simButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sim);
        RadioButton naoButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.nao);
        RadioButton naButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.na);

        //populando as Views
        potencial.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getPotencial()));
        questao.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getQuestao()));
        titulo.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getTitulo()));

        RadioGroup radioGroupAmc = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAmc);
        flag = mensal.get(position);
        radioGroupAmc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case sim:

                        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = true;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = false;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = false;;

                        // trata radioValor1
                        break;
                    case nao:
                        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = false;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = true;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = false;
                        // trata radioValor2
                        break;
                    case na:
                        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = false;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = false;
                        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = true;
                        // trata radioValor3
                        break;
                }

            }

        });



     if( flag.radioButtonValues[0] == true )
        {
            simButton.setChecked(true);
            naoButton.setChecked(false);
            naButton.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if(flag.radioButtonValues[1] == true ){
                naoButton.setChecked(true);
                simButton.setChecked(false);
                naButton.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                if(flag.radioButtonValues[2] == true ){
                    naButton.setChecked(true);
                    simButton.setChecked(false);
                    naoButton.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                    simButton.setChecked(false);
                    naoButton.setChecked(false);
                    naButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

No trecho a seguir, eu verifico a posição que está a minha listview (flag) e verifico o valor que está dentro do  `radioButtonValues[]`.

```
   if( flag.radioButtonValues[0] == true )
        {
            simButton.setChecked(true);
            naoButton.setChecked(false);
            naButton.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if(flag.radioButtonValues[1] == true ){
                naoButton.setChecked(true);
                simButton.setChecked(false);
                naButton.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                if(flag.radioButtonValues[2] == true ){
                    naButton.setChecked(true);
                    simButton.setChecked(false);
                    naoButton.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                    simButton.setChecked(false);
                    naoButton.setChecked(false);
                    naButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Classe AvaliacaoMensal:

```
 class AvaliacaoMensal {
        private String questao;
        private char potencial;
        private String titulo;
       boolean[] radioButtonValues = new boolean[3];
//Gets e sets
```

Mas não está funcionando da forma esperada, pois a marcação está indo para outro RadioGroup, algúem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: No ultimo `if`, insira um `else { naButton.setChecked(false); }`

Comment: @acklay Pq? não entendi.

Comment: Estou vendo que sem tem o true mas não tem false. Você tem que criar uma negação também caso não seja true. Então no final vc está criando um if sem else. Tenta adicionar o else caso não seja verdadeiro. `if(flag.radioButtonValues[2] == true ){
    naButton.setChecked(true);
} else { naButton.setChecked(false); }`

Comment: @acklay Então no último else eu teria que colocar `}else {
                        simButton.setChecked(false);
                        naoButton.setChecked(false);
                        naButton.setChecked(false);
                    }` Mas não mudou em nada não =[

Comment: Isso mesmo Lucas... estou pedindo pra fazer assim pra ver se dá certo! =D

Comment: @acklay SIm sim faz sentido. Mas não deu não :(

Comment: Também tem o botão simButton que você tem que colocar  simButton.setChecked(false) em algum momento.

Comment: Sua lógica está bem estranha. hehe

Comment: @acklay Uai ... eu verifico na posição Flag se determinado radioButton está marcado, caso esteja eu dou setCheked nele. Foi o melhor que consegui pensar  HAHAH :(

Comment: Não precisa comparar se é `true`, basta fazer `if(flag.radioButtonValues[0]){ ... bla bla bla}`.... Isso já significa que é `true`. Veja a resposta do ramaral, talvez assim resolva seu problema. Exatamente o que estava tentando dizer.

Comment: @acklay desculpe ter respondido, mas já estava a fazê-lo quando vi os seus comentários.

Comment: @ramaral Relaxa! Principal objetivo do SO é trabalhar em conjunto para ajudar o próximo! Acho que estamos cumprindo isso. =D

Comment: @acklay Eu sei, mas não gosto de me meter(não vejo necessidade) quando alguém já está a ajudar e vai no bom caminho.

Comment: Ao editar a pergunta com o código actualizado com aquele da resposta você deixa a resposta sem sentido. Quem ler agora a pergunta vai dizer que eu para responder copiei o código da pergunta.

Comment: @LucasCharles Não é legal você editar uma pergunta inserindo conteúdo de respostas de pessoas que tentaram te ajudar. Isso acaba invalidando as respostas. O interessante é conversar e tentar resolver a partir do que já possui.

Comment: O que tem na classe AvaliacaoMensal? Tem como mostrar o conteúdo dela?!

Comment: @acklay Ok, editei minha pergunta. :)

Comment: Porque está usando o `flag = mensal.get(position);` se já possui o final `AvaliacaoMensal mensalAmc = mensal.get(position)`;. Não deveria estar comparando o `mensalAmc`

Comment: @acklay meu flag estava pegando valores aleatórios. Só não sei pq. MUITO OBRIGADO!